# Postgresql c function timestamp convert

Tags: c, postgresql

inside a custom **C function** how can convert a string (es. '2012-01-10') date into unix timestamp?

I mean is there some C trick to do the job or some casting? or I need to use SQL 
calling:

```
SELECT extract(epoch FROM date('2012-01-10'));
```

is not this a loss of performance?

I've seen an example with

```
PGtimestamptz ts; 
res = PQexef("select now()"); 
PQgetf(res, 0, "%timestamptz", 0 , &ts); 
int epoch = ts.epoch;
```

I've install libpqtypes but it seems that the example is incomplete and it doesn't work

could someone suggest the best way for this conversion and/or provide e full example using libpqtypes developing a postgresql custom C function?

I use PostgreSQl 9.3 on a Linux box

thanks a lot

Luca

Comment: You do know that Postgres is open source and written in C, right? :-)

Comment: Yes thanks, but I'm totally new in c so .., thanks for help.

Comment: My C is to rusty to add an answer, but googling for "c epoch from date" yields lots of results.

Comment: my guess is you should fill a `struct tm` with the contents of the `PGtimsamptz` and use that as an argument for the `mktime()` function, which is part of the standard library. The timezone part can get tricky, if you would like to handle that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside PostgreSQL (server side) (you talk about PostgreSQL custom function), you can use a two possible paths:

a) you can call "in" function for expected type - timestamp
b) you can call to_time function

A related call can look like:

```
Timestamp t;

t = DatumGetTimestamp(DirectFunctionCall2(to_timestamp,
                               CStringGetTextDatum("2013-08-15"),
                               CStringGetTextDatum("YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

Sure, you can use a POSIX libraries, but then you cannot be sure about portability and future compatibility. This is server side - and you will use this technique for PostgreSQL custom C function.

On client side depends on expected speed. Using server side conversion via SQL call is usually simply, portable and mostly speed enough solution. Typical bottle neck is IO, so you don't need to optimize CPU in typical use cases - and you can use a simply and portable solutions (using text instead binary). Some info about PGtimestamp is there http://libpqtypes.esilo.com/man3/pqt-handlers.html

Comment: Hi Pavel, thanks again for suggestion, there are so few documentations  on c function developement in postgresql.. Can I ask you which way I can declare a function as to_timestamp before using as you suggest? I receive error: ‘to_timestamp’ undeclared (first use in this function) compiling. And also how cast Timestamp to integer?

Comment: God start is looking to source code of PostgreSQL contrib extensions. Next other inspiration can be some third party pg extensions - like orafce, .. to_timestamp function is declared in "utils/formatting.h" header file. A most simply way is installation Pg from source code tarball. You can prepare a new own custom extension by cloning some simple contrib extension like cube or citext.